# Mat-checkbox checked not changing checkbox state

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm implementing a language switch component which display checkboxes, one for each language of the app (translations with `@ngx-translate`).

When clicking one of the checkbox, app language is correctly switched but the clicked mat-checkbox is still unchecked.

Template :

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage == 'en'" (click)="switchLanguage('en')">English</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage == 'fr'" (click)="switchLanguage('fr')">French</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage == 'de'" (click)="switchLanguage('de')">German</mat-checkbox>
```

Component :

```
export class CheckboxOverviewExample {
  public selectedLanguage: string;

  constructor(){
    this.selectedLanguage = 'fr';
  }

  public switchLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.selectedLanguage = lang;
    // this.translateService.use(lang); // changing ngx-translate language
    console.log('Switched to ' + lang);
  }
}
```

The `[checked]` binding is working when you route to the component. The `mat-checkbox` for french is indeed checked when landing to the component (default value). Now when I click on german or english, the language does switch, the french checkbox does correctly uncheck, however the clicked checkbox does not check.

I'm missing something, might be a small detail, but I do not understand why the german / english does not check while the french does correctly uncheck.

Have a look at [this simple stackblitz code](https://angular-hjeezr-wcxytp.stackblitz.io) to reproduce my case.

Comment: Why don't you use ngModel instead of checked?

Comment: `ngModel` should map to a boolean value I do not have. I have a `language` field which can take several string values. Moreover, the number of languages can increase due to app parameters (in my real code, checkboxes are rendered with a `*ngFor` directive).

Comment: Use radio button, that will allow you to bind language property as ngModel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

so I have an answer for you. don't need to use a radio button as your designer hate it just use

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage === 'en'" (change)="switchLanguage('en')">English</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage === 'fr'" (change)="switchLanguage('fr')">French</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage ==='de'" (change)="switchLanguage('de')">German</mat-checkbox>
```

check for type and value too using `selectedLanguage === 'en'`

also, use `(change)="switchLanguage('de')` instead of click

working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajo6cr-ocwm8k?file=app/radio-overview-example.html) 
or check [this](https://angular-ajo6cr-ocwm8k.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `(click)` and `(change)` ? It's working but I'd like to understand why one is working and not the other. Both should trigger a change detection cycle to my knowledge.

Comment: as you can also check, in given stackblitz using change method is fired when checkbox losses focus and click method on click so if you used clicked instead of changed you need to click the element twice to check and in some browser, it will be difficult for a user so it's better to use change.

Comment: in my solution it will also work on click but you need to double-click the checkbox to get click

Answer (score 8):

You should use **`(change)`** instead of **`(click)`**. Your template should be changed to this:

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage === 'en'" (change)="switchLanguage($event, 'en')">English</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage === 'fr'" (change)="switchLanguage($event, 'fr')">French</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedLanguage === 'de'" (change)="switchLanguage($event, 'de')">German</mat-checkbox>
```

... and your function will look like this:

```
public switchLanguage(event: MatCheckboxChange, lang: string) {
    if(event.checked && this.selectedLanguage!== lang){
        this.selectedLanguage = lang;
        // this.translateService.use(lang); // changing ngx-translate language
        console.log('Switched to ' + lang);
    }
}
```

Remember to import **`MatCheckboxChange`**

```
import { MatCheckboxChange} from '@angular/material';`
```

Link to [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7gr9y?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.ts).

---

You should use [**radio buttons**](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview) for this behavior. Checkbox is not the correct way to go when you only have to allow a single option selection.

```
<mat-radio-group [value]="selectedLanguage">
  <mat-radio-button value="en" (click)="switchLanguage('en')">English</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="fr" (click)="switchLanguage('fr')">French</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="de" (click)="switchLanguage('de')">German</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Here is a [**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajo6cr?file=app/radio-overview-example.ts).

Comment: I understand your point, but you are not answering to the question, which is not if there exist another component I can/should use. I have to use a checkbox because our web designer did use it on his app mock-up. It's a visual choice (might be our designer hates radios).

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `(click)` and `(change)` ? It's working but I'd like to understand why one is working and not the other. Both should trigger a change detection cycle to my knowledge.

Comment: For me, changing (click) with (change) did the trick, thank you

Comment: Hi, I've  just changed click by change event and this woks for me.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to other answers you can choose not to use a separate function to handle the `change` event, but instead assign a value like this:
`(change)="myBooleanVar = $event.source.checked"` This example does not work in OP's case, but might be useful to other people who use checkboxes to assign yes/no values.

Answer (score 2):

(click) is a DOM event, whereas (change) is generated from the Angular framework.

Click will have a generic DOM event object, and Change the MatCheckboxChange object.

Click fires first.