# Angular: why does (change) event for checkbox only trigger after double click?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, checkbox

I have an Angular application with a checkbox list (mat-checkbox) that is properly displaying the English or Spanish values depending on locale.

**Problem**: However, the checkbox itself is not consistently being checked when the user clicks on it. It appears to require a double click. What could cause something like this?

**I've tried**:

- I have looked into [checkex] and (change).
- I have tried changing my
  objects/class/interface.
- I've looked through Angular documentation.
- I've done console.log on everything I could find
- I've looked through SO articles such as:
  [Mat-checkbox checked not changing checkbox state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749308/mat-checkbox-checked-not-changing-checkbox-state)

**component.html**:

```
<div class="student-history-checkbox" *ngFor="let item of gradesInCurrentLanguage()">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="isChecked(item.ID)" (change)="onChangeCB($event, item.ID)">{{item.Value}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

**component.ts**:

```
public gradesInCurrentLanguage() : CGenericRecord[] {
    return this.ms.XFormForLocale(this.grades, this.localeId);
}


isChecked(ID : number)
{
    return (this.gradeInfo.Grades.indexOf(ID) > -1) ? true : false;
}



onChangeCB(event : any, id : number)
{
    if(event.checked && this.gradeInfo.Grades.indexOf(id) == -1){
        this.gradeInfo.Grades.push(id);
    }else{
        let index = this.gradeInfo.Grades.indexOf(id);
        this.gradeInfo.Grades.splice(index, 1);
    }       
}
```

**interface.ts**:

```
export class CGenericRecord
{
    constructor(
        public ID: number, 
        public Value: string) 
    {}
}
export interface GenericTranslationRecord {
    ID      :   number,
    Value   :   string,
    SpanishValue: string
}
```

**service.ts**:

```
public XFormForLocale(grades: GenericTranslationRecord[], localeId: string) : CGenericRecord[] {
    let recs :CGenericRecord[] = [];
    for (let g of grades) 
    {
        recs.push( new CGenericRecord(d.ID, localeId === "es" ? d.SpanishValue : d.Value));
    }
    return recs;
}
```

**Expected result**: Checkbox should show that it is checked when the user clicks on it once. It should also show that it is unchecked after one click.

**Actual result**: Checkbox is only checked after multiple clicks

Comment: NOT use [checked], just use [(ngModel)]="variable" and change the variable to true/false. Really it's not very efficient in each change push and slice an array. It's better,e.g. use a getter `get selected(){return item.filter(x=>x.selected).map(o=>o.id)}` -or not use a getter and call to the function only one time-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above was resulting in an infinite loop. Instead of having the method in the ngFor, I made a variable in the typescript and set it = to the method. Then I used that variable in the HTML. It works now.

HTML:

```
<div class="student-history-checkbox" *ngFor="let item of gradesInCurrentLanguageVar">
```

TS:

```
this.gradesInCurrentLanguagevar = gradesInCurrentLanguage();
```